# Wrong result comparing GETDATE() to stored GETDATE() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would expect the result to always be 1:

```
DECLARE @x datetime2
SELECT @x=GETDATE()
SELECT CASE WHEN @x>GETDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

But it is sometimes 1 and sometimes 0.
How is that possible?

Comment: Microseconds may be different depending on server speed.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, assume no two events ever happen at exactly the same time....

Comment: I'd expect the result to always be 0.

Comment: Please have a closer look at the code.
When you get 0 it means that the first GETDATE() has a greater value than the second GETDATE().
That should not be possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It takes time for code to execute. Sometimes a tick happens in between lines two and three, and sometimes (usually) not. In the latter case (no tick), `@x` is still equal to (not greater than) the `GETDATE()` value in the third line and you end up with `0`. What surprised me at first is you ever see `1`. When a tick does happen, `@x` should now be less than the new `GETDATE()` value in line 3 and you'd still see `0`.

But it makes more sense when you run this code:

```
DECLARE @x datetime2
SELECT @x=GETDATE()
SELECT @x, GETDATE(), CASE WHEN @x>GETDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Now we can see what's going on better. Here's a sample result on my machine:

```
2018-01-19 23:32:21.3833333   |  2018-01-19 23:32:21.383   |    1
```

Ahhh... `@x` is a `datetime2` with more precision than the older `datetime` used by `GETDATE()`. And you can see in the [documentation for GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) that it does return a `datetime` rather than `datetime2`. So we have some rounding error going on between the two values.

For the `0` values, I ran the altered code 30 or 40 times (hitting F5 for refresh), and **ALL** of the `0`'s I saw looked like this:

```
2018-01-19 23:36:29.0366667   |   2018-01-19 23:36:29.037   |   0
```

Where the last digit in the second column was a 7 and the first column had repeating 6's with a rounded 7 at the end.

One thing still confuses me. The `GETDATE()` function returns a `datetime` value, but somehow it assigns `datetime2` precision to `@x`. I'd expect to just see extra zeros that always match the original `GETDATE()` result.

Comment: Using `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` would return `DATETIME2` datatype with the same precision as `@x`

Comment: @csname1910 great answer indeed. please consider accepting it.